# Assign properties to execute package task ssis object using biml

Tags: sql-server, ssis, biml

using biml (via BIDS helper in visual studio) how do i assign values to the properties of the SSIS 2008 Execute Package Task object, specifically

- Location: SQL Server
- Connection: SomeConnectionString

using BIML. I have searched for many hours and  cannot find how to set these properties

Comment: Could you edit your question to show the biml you have surrounding your `ExecutePackage` tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside your `ExecutePackage` tag, you'll need to specify that it's a `SqlServer` source.

In the following declaration, I create two connection managers, one for a file based connection manager and one for a SQL connection to my named instance.

The Biml itself creates 2 packages. A Child and Parent. The Parent package creates two Execute Package Tasks

```
<Biml xmlns="http://schemas.varigence.com/biml.xsd">
  <Connections>
    <FileConnection Name="FCChild" FilePath="c:\Users\bfellows\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\SSISPOC\PackageDeploymentModel\Child.dtsx"></FileConnection>
    <OleDbConnection Name="OLEChild" ConnectionString="Data Source=localhost\dev2012;Initial Catalog=tempdb;Provider=SQLNCLI10.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;"></OleDbConnection>
  </Connections>
  <Packages>
    <Package Name="Child"
             ConstraintMode="Linear"
             >
    </Package>
    <Package Name="Parent" 
             ConstraintMode="Linear">
      <Tasks>
        <ExecutePackage Name="EPT File Child">
          <File ConnectionName="FCChild"></File>
        </ExecutePackage>

        <ExecutePackage Name="EPT SS Child">
          <SqlServer ConnectionName="OLEChild" PackagePath="\Child"></SqlServer>
        </ExecutePackage>
      </Tasks>
    </Package>
  </Packages>
</Biml>
```

The resulting Execute Package Task for the SQL Server appears as

[image]